# Webserver Problem, Micropython, Raspberry pi pico W

Tags: html, webserver, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

**In the following code i'm trying to access the Bew Page, but i'm not able to do that.
please help me to find where the problem exactly is**

```
from machine import ADC, Pin
import utime
import network
import time
import socket
import uasyncio as asyncio
from picozero import pico_temp_sensor
import os

soil = ADC(Pin(28))
pump = Pin(5, Pin.OUT)
min_moisture = 15971
max_moisture = 44458
prev_value = 0
read_delay = 1
current_file = None
pump_state = "off"
save_interval = 0.5
factor = 0.05
vsys_adc = ADC(Pin(26))
R1 = 1000 
R2 = 1000
voltage_divider_ratio = R2 / (R1 + R2)
moisture = 0
vsys_voltage_value = 0
temperature = 0
ssid = '***********'
password = '******************'
wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF) #network.WLAN object is configured as a station (client) interface
network.hostname("pico")
here is the html code 
HTML = """\ #html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Irrigation System</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Smart Irrigation System</h1>
<p>Moisture: {moisture}%</p>
<p>Temperature: {temperature} C</p>
<p>Battery Voltage: {voltage} V</p>
<p>Pump State: {pump_state}</p>
<button onclick="fetch('/pump/on')">Turn Pump ON</button>
<button onclick="fetch('/pump/off')">Turn Pump OFF</button>
</body>
</html>
"""
**here is connecting to the network** 
def connect_to_network(): #connect to network
    wlan.active(True) #activate the wireless LAN interface
    wlan.config(pm = 0xa11140) #pwoer management: always on
    wlan.connect(ssid, password)
    
    max_wait = 10 #representing the maximum number of seconds to wait for the connection
    while max_wait > 0: #The while loop runs as long as max_wait is greater than 0, meaning that there is still time left to wait for the connectio
        if wlan.status() < 0 or wlan.status() >= 3: #If the status is less than 0 (indicating an error) or greater than or equal to 3 (indicating a successful connection)
            break #break out of the loop
        max_wait -= 1
        print('waiting for connection...')
        time.sleep(1)

    if wlan.status() != 3:
        raise RuntimeError('network connect failed')
    else:
        print('connected')
        status = wlan.ifconfig()
        print('ip = ' + status[0])
     **and here is the serve client function** 
async def serve_client(reader, writer): #webserver
    print("Got a request")
    request_line = await reader.readline()
    method, path, _ = request_line.split(b" ")
    print("Method: ", method)
    print("Path: ", path)
    if method == b"GET" and path == b"/":
        # Read the latest measurements
        moisture = await read_moisture_measurement()
        temperature = await read_temperature()
        voltage = await read_battery_voltage()
        pump_state = pump.value()
        # Generate the HTML response
        response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
        response += HTML.format(moisture=moisture, temperature=temperature, voltage=voltage, pump_state=pump_state)
        await writer.awrite(response.encode())
    elif method == b"GET" and path == b"/pump/on":
        pump.on()  # Turn pump on
        response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\nPump turned on"
        await writer.awrite(response)
    elif method == b"GET" and path == b"/pump/off":
        pump.off()  # Turn pump off
        response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\nPump turned off"
        await writer.awrite(response)
    else:
        response = "HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND\r\n\r\nPage Not Found"
        await writer.awrite(response)
    await writer.aclose()
        
        
def format_timestamp(timestamp):
    tm = utime.localtime(timestamp)
    return "{:04d}_{:02d}_{:02d}_{:02d}_{:02d}_{:02d}".format(tm[0], tm[1], tm[2], tm[3], tm[4], tm[5])


def measurement_filter(basic_value, factor): #This function applies a filter to the given basic_value using the previous value and a factor
    filtered_moisture=basic_value * factor + prev_value * (1-factor)
    prev_moisture = filtered_moisture
    return filtered_moisture

**Measuremnt**
async def read_moisture_measurement():
        raw_moisture = (max_moisture - soil.read_u16()) * 100 / (max_moisture - min_moisture)
        moisture = measurement_filter(raw_moisture, factor) 
        return moisture
       
async def read_temperature():
    
        temperature = pico_temp_sensor.temp
        return temperature
   
async def read_battery_voltage():

        vsys_voltage_value = vsys_adc.read_u16() * 3.3 / voltage_divider_ratio / 65535
        return vsys_voltage_value
    
class StoreMeasurement:
    def __init__(self):
        self.moisture = None
        self.temperature = None
        self.battery_voltage = None
        self.pump_state = None
        
        
async def control_water_pump(moisture, pump_on_time, pump_needs_reset):
    pump_on_time = 0
    pump_timeout = 10
    current_time = utime.time()

    # If moisture level is low and pump doesn't need a reset
    if moisture < 30 and not pump_needs_reset:
        # If pump is not already turned on
        if not pump.value():
            pump.on()
            pump_on_time = current_time

    # If moisture level is high
    elif moisture >= 80:
        # If pump is turned on
        if pump.value():
            pump.off()
            pump_on_time = 0
            # Reset the pump only if it has run for at least pump_timeout seconds
            if current_time - pump_on_time >= pump_timeout:
                pump_needs_reset = True

    # If pump is turned on and running for more than pump_timeout seconds
    if pump.value() and current_time - pump_on_time >= pump_timeout:
        pump.off()
        pump_on_time = 0
        pump_needs_reset = True  # Prevent the pump from turning on until the moisture level reaches 80%

    return pump_on_time, pump_needs_reset

async def save_measurement_to_file(data):
    global current_file, current_file_creation_time
    manage_files()
    
    timestamp = utime.time()
    formatted_timestamp = format_timestamp(timestamp)
    
    current_file.write(f'{formatted_timestamp};{str(round(data.moisture, 2)).replace(".", ",")};{str(round(data.temperature, 2)).replace(".", ",")};{str(round(data.vsys_voltage_value, 2)).replace(".", ",")};{data.pump_state}\n')

def manage_files():
    global current_file, current_file_creation_time
    current_time = utime.time()

    if current_file is None or current_time - current_file_creation_time >= 3600:
        if current_file is not None:
            current_file.close()
                    
        current_timestamp = format_timestamp(current_time)
            
        file_name = current_timestamp + '.csv'
            
        current_file = open(file_name, 'w')
            
        current_file.write("Timestamp;Moisture;Temperature;Voltage;State\n")
            
        current_file_creation_time = current_time
            
        file_list = [f for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith('.csv')]
            
        if len(file_list) > 24: 
            file_list.sort()
            oldest_file_name = file_list[0]
            os.remove(oldest_file_name)
        
async def irrigation_task():
    #global moisture, temperature, vsys_voltage_value, irrigation_log
    data = StoreMeasurement()
    pump_on_time = 0
    pump_needs_reset = False
    while True:
        data.moisture = await read_moisture_measurement()
        data.temperature = await read_temperature()
        data.vsys_voltage_value = await read_battery_voltage()
        print(f'Moisture: {data.moisture:.2f}, Temperature: {data.temperature:.2f}, Battery Voltage: {data.vsys_voltage_value:.2f}')
        pump_on_time, pump_needs_reset = await control_water_pump(data.moisture, pump_on_time, pump_needs_reset)
        data.pump_state = pump.value()
        await save_measurement_to_file(data)
        await asyncio.sleep(read_delay)

async def webserver_task():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(serve_client, "0.0.0.0", 80)
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(read_delay)

async def main():
    connect_to_network()
    irrigation_handeler = asyncio.create_task(irrigation_task())
    print("irrigation_task:", irrigation_task)
    webserver_handeler = asyncio.create_task(webserver_task())
    print("Webserver started on {}:{}".format(wlan.ifconfig()[0], 80))

    await asyncio.gather(irrigation_handeler, webserver_handeler)

asyncio.run(main())
```

**it's a smart Irrigation System Micropython Code.                                                                                                                                                                                    this code is running on a raspberry pi pico W.                                                                                                                                 I want to implement a Web Server serve a web page, via the web page i must be able to control the water pump manually, and i must display the Measurements.**